# Pydantic root_validator with pre=True recieves dicts instead of actual input object

Tags: python, validation, parsing, pydantic

I have two pydantic models, `A` and `B`. Model `B` is a kind of refactoring of `A`, and should be able to parse its values natively.

I constructed a `root_validator` with `pre=True`, which checks for instances of `A` and parses them into a normal `B` object.

The pydantic docs state:

> root validators can have `pre=True`, in which case they're called before
> field validation occurs (and are provided with the raw input data)

However, against expected behaviour, the `A` objects are passed into the validator as its `dict()` rather than the "raw" object passed, meaning I can't detect them in the validator, and pydantic tries to parse them as a field value dicts.

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround?

### MWE

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str

class B(BaseModel):
    c: int
    d: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def parse_a_obj(cls, values):
        if isinstance(values, A):
            return cls(c=values.a, d=values.b)
        print(values)
        return values


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(a=1, b='2')
    B.parse_obj(a)
```

```py
{'a': 1, 'b': '2'}
---------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [3], line 21
     19 if __name__ == '__main__':
     20     a = A(a=1, b='2')
---> 21     B.parse_obj(a)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:526, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.parse_obj()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 2 validation errors for B
c
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
d
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

(Obviously, `A` and `B` are allegories for more complex and useful models)

Comment: Did you take a look at the output of your print statement? It shows you that `values` is a dictionary. This also seems to be questionable misuse of validators IMO. I would suggest writing a dedicated class method for this that does basically what you are doing inside that validator and simply creates an instance of `B` from an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

The `.parse_obj` method is meant to be called with a dict (basically, it is expecting a dict that you would use liek `MyModel(**some_dict)`.

If the object it receives is not a dict, [it is coerced to a dict](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/f7ff485fd705eaffb261fa2adb5b68d7f3d9758c/pydantic/main.py#L517):

```
@classmethod
def parse_obj(cls: Type['Model'], obj: Any) -> 'Model':
    obj = cls._enforce_dict_if_root(obj)
    if not isinstance(obj, dict):
        try:
            obj = dict(obj)
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            exc = TypeError(f'{cls.__name__} expected dict not {obj.__class__.__name__}')
            raise ValidationError([ErrorWrapper(exc, loc=ROOT_KEY)], cls) from e
    return cls(**obj)
```

And from [the tutorial](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#helper-functions):

> `parse_obj`: this is very similar to the `__init__` method of the model,
> except it takes a dict rather than keyword arguments. If the object
> passed is not a dict a `ValidationError` will be raised.

Note, if you had used another type that wasn't coercable to a dict, e.g. `class Foo: pass`, then you would have gotten:

```
B.parse_obj(Foo())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:522, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.parse_obj()

TypeError: 'Foo' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [21], line 1
----> 1 B.parse_obj(Foo())

File ~/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:525, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.parse_obj()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for B
__root__
  B expected dict not Foo (type=type_error)
```

So you aren't using this method the way it was meant to be used. You dont want a *validator*, you just want a regular alternative constructor, something like:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str

class B(BaseModel):
    c: int
    d: str

    @classmethod
    def from_a_obj(cls, a: A):
        # maybe you want: if not isinstance(a, A): raise TypeError("expected A instance, got:", type(a))
        return cls(c=a.a, d=a.b)

a = A(a=1, b='2')
b = B.from_a_obj(a)
```

Comment: Was about to post the same.